# Shiny R DT: display the filtered column criterium (ranges/choices) in a second table or as a text

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to display the filtered column criterium from datatable DT in Shiny R in a form of text or table (so that the user knows what he/she filtered while browsing through other tabs in `ShinyApp`).

Here is very simple example (no tabs) just to display:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

x <- as.numeric(1:1000000)
y <- as.numeric(1:1000000)
data <- data.frame(x,y)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tableId'),
                 plotOutput('plot1')),
  server = function(input, output) {    
    output$tableId = renderDataTable({
      datatable(data, options = list(pageLength = 100, lengthMenu=c(100,200,300,400,500,600)))
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      filtered_data <- data[input$tableId_rows_all, ]
      ggplot(data=filtered_data, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line()
    })
  }
)
```

So for example **if we filter x column from 10-100**, is it possible to display it as a text under the plot (and in my original `ShinyApp` in the other tab in `tabsetPanel`): `X column has been filtered 10-100` or anything like that.

Thanks for any tips!

Cheers

Comment: In your example you havent filter for columns -- only for full dt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get such info from `tableId_search_columns`

for example

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

x <- as.numeric(1:10000)
y <- as.numeric(1:10000)
data <- data.frame(x,y)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tableId'),
                 plotOutput('plot1'),
                 verbatimTextOutput("txt")),
  server = function(input, output) {    
    output$tableId = renderDataTable({
      datatable(data,filter="top", options = list(pageLength = 100, lengthMenu=c(100,200,300,400,500,600)))
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({

      filtered_data <- data[input$tableId_rows_all, ]
      ggplot(data=filtered_data, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line()
    })
    output$txt=renderText({
      aa=""
      for ( i in 1:length(input$tableId_search_columns)){
        if(input$tableId_search_columns[[i]]!=""){
        aa=paste0(aa,"\n","column ",i, "filter ",input$tableId_search_columns[[i]])}
      }
      aa
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Just last question, is it possible to get the column name instead of columnId?

Comment: `colnames(data)[i]` ?

Comment: Thanks for saving me lots of time! It is working! and sorry for so many questions!